# Querying the same table twice to get 2 records..in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm using SQL Server 2016, but this is not a 2016 question. Here's what I would like to do. I will have the user's email address and will need to get data for that user. So this is simple:

```
select [firstname],[lastname],[managerid] from employees where workemail='emp@company.com'
```

Very straight forward, but notice i'm pulling the manager's id. And i now need the exact same data for the manager, sans the manager's id:

```
select [firstname],[lastname] from employees where mamangerid=manager_id_from_employee_query
```

You can see all data is in the same table. I could stop here because I have my data, but I love to learn and look for better solutions. How can i achieve what I'm trying to do without having to write 2 separate SQL statements or what would be the better solution?

Comment: did you try self-join?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a left-join.  The left side expression will have the employee, and the right side will link to a row in the same table and get the manager's info (assuming it exists).  Don't do an inner join because if the "manager" row is missing, then you'll get nothing for the employee.

```
Select  [e].[firstname] [emp_fname]
  , [e].[lastname] [emp_lname]
  , Manager.[firstname] [mgr_fname]
  , Manager.[lastname] [mgr_lname]
From    [employees] [e]
    Left Join [employees] Manager
        On [e].[employee_id] = Manager.[managerid]
```

Comment: This is why I asked the question. I wanted to learn something and I did. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self join where the first instance of the table indicated the employee's details and the second the manager's details:

```
SELECT    e.[firstname], e.[lastname], m.[firstname], m.[lastname]
FROM      employees e
LEFT JOIN employees m ON e.[managerid] = m.[id]
WHERE     e.workemail = 'emp@company.com'
```

Comment: This won't work if the "manager" row is missing, it will return 0 rows.  Must use a left or right join.

Comment: Hey Mureinik, great answer, upvoted it. Could I possibly have you review my answer? I am studying php currently and would love to know if mine would work as well. Yours also seems a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the right result:

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname FROM employees a RIGHT JOIN 
  (SELECT managerid FROM employees WHERE workemail = 'emp@company.com') b 
WHERE a.managerid = b.managerid
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the required output - OP is asking for the manager's first and last name.

Comment: a right join forces this to only return when a manager exists - also sub queries are usually slower

Comment: @Mureinik Interesting, wouldn't my query produce the first and last name given the initial part of the sql statement: `SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname`?

Comment: @Webeng it will produce the name of the employee, not the manager alongside it. You'll need to add "b.firstname, b.lastname" to the select list.

Comment: @ChrisJ The sub query part taking longer totally makes sense yeah. In the case that manager doesn't exist, was there supposed to be something returned? I would think that an empty result is what is wanted when there is no manager to be found.

Comment: @Mureinik Oh I see... so analysing my query, the `SELECT` inside the brackets would obtain a column of `managerid`. The result table would be considered `b`. Isn't `b` the resulting row of the employee and not the manager? If so, then why would `b.firstname, b.lastname` be the manager?